# Python2 "raise e[0], e[1], e[2]" and python3 version in one file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've found that python 3 equivalent of:

```
raise e[0], e[1], e[2]
```

will look something like this:

```
raise e[0](e[1]).with_traceback(e[2])
```

But I get either syntax error for the 1st (in python 3) or `object has no attribute 'with_traceback'` (in python 2)

How to write these lines for both versions without errors?

Comment: @pxl: But the other syntax still will throw a syntax error in Python 3..

Comment: Have to agree with @MartijnPieters. First thing I tried was `if six.PY3: ... else: ...`. But I had a syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like [`six.reraise`](http://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.reraise) is what you're after.

Example of raising an exception with a different traceback that works both in py2 and py3:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import six


def this_should_show_up_in_the_traceback():
    raise ValueError("an exception")

try:
    this_should_show_up_in_the_traceback()
except:
    type, value, tb = sys.exc_info()

print('stashed a traceback for later', type, value, tb)

six.reraise(IndexError, IndexError("other exception"), tb)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [PEP 3109 -- Raising Exceptions in Python 3000](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3109/#compatibility-issues) in section **Compatibility Issues**

> Three-expression raise statements will be converted from
>
> ```
> raise E, V, T
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> e = E(V)
> e.__traceback__ = T
> raise e
> ```

In your example

```
ex = e[0](e[1])
ex.__traceback__ = e[2]
raise ex
```